# How to bypass RunTimeWarnings: Overflow encountered in power

Tags: python, arrays

I have a code as such;

```
A1 = 0.394
A2 = -1.19e-04
A3 = 1.5305e-15
A4 = 0.674
A5 = 1.229e-04
A6 = 1.9202e-05
A7 = 136.035
A8 = -7680.41
A9 = -48.595
Temp_ = np.array([274,275,276,284,285,286,294,295,296,314,315,316,324,325,326])
Pressure =np.array([6.6,15,25,100,250,400,500,650,750,850,950,1150,1250,1350,1450])
Delta_LogK500 = A1 + A2*(Temp_-273.15) + A3*((Temp_-273.15)**6)
Delta_LogK1000 = A4 + A5*(Temp_-273.15) + A6*((Temp_-273.15)**6)
```

Then I tried to do this;

```
for pressure in Pressure:
if pressure <=500:
    LogKsp_BaSO4 = A7 + A8/Temp_ + A9*(np.log10(Temp_)) + (pressure/500)*Delta_LogK500
else:
    LogKsp_BaSO4 = A7 + A8/Temp_ + A9*(np.log10(Temp_)) + Delta_LogK500 + ((pressure-500)/500)*(Delta_LogK1000-Delta_LogK500)
Ksp_BaSO4 = 10**LogKsp_BaSO4
```

Then I get a RunTimeWarning as this;
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power
How can I rectify this?

Comment: I don't get any such warning - but I do get a lot of `inf` values for higher pressure values, so I guess that you have `numpy`'s warnings configured differently than the default.  I'm pretty sure you have at least one of the equations entered incorrectly - I would assume that the below/above 500 versions should produce similar results for values near 500, but in fact they're vastly different.

Answer (score 0):

your data seem to have some very large numbers that numpy cannot store in double precision,
if you know that the results are supposed to be that big and that your formulas/numbers are correct then you should use something with an arbitary precision instead of doubles such as [mpmath](https://mpmath.org/) as shown below.

```py
import numpy as np
from mpmath import mp
mp.dps = 50 # set precision of mpmath
A1 = 0.394
A2 = -1.19e-04
A3 = 1.5305e-15
A4 = 0.674
A5 = 1.229e-04
A6 = 1.9202e-05
A7 = 136.035
A8 = -7680.41
A9 = -48.595
Temp_ = np.array([274,275,276,284,285,286,294,295,296,314,315,316,324,325,326])
Pressure =np.array([6.6,15,25,100,250,400,500,650,750,850,950,1150,1250,1350,1450])
Delta_LogK500 = A1 + A2*(Temp_-273.15) + A3*((Temp_-273.15)**6)
Delta_LogK1000 = A4 + A5*(Temp_-273.15) + A6*((Temp_-273.15)**6)

for pressure in Pressure:
    if pressure <=500:
        LogKsp_BaSO4 = A7 + A8/Temp_ + A9*(np.log10(Temp_)) + (pressure/500)*Delta_LogK500
    else:
        LogKsp_BaSO4 = A7 + A8/Temp_ + A9*(np.log10(Temp_)) + Delta_LogK500 + ((pressure-500)/500)*(Delta_LogK1000-Delta_LogK500)
Ksp_BaSO4 = [] # store in list instead of numpy array.
for x in LogKsp_BaSO4:
    Ksp_BaSO4.append(mp.power(10,x))
print(Ksp_BaSO4)
```

> [mpf('0.0000000002938469906929447850083334542219744007588028502421'),
> mpf('0.00000000031257687994019270314333562958577525350876048587075356'),
> mpf('0.00000000034512183989764743999706129851416059282202510548218884'),
> mpf('167543659733581552845708891966883126964935495656872.75'),
> mpf('5.5423700129574568139561798851250722604364805682197283e+91'),
> mpf('9.9718890936781592310728280710630978477478900524773463e+154'),
> mpf('1.7288921040438659292780185142573524424415846253639323e+2988'),
> mpf('1.1983816534578003829479717018493666219250587885076217e+3961'),
> mpf('8.2549931077633685994591561424516533421617872709857998e+5183'),
> mpf('2.9371418939277946324926145793795520788502099157110799e+169523'),
> mpf('5.6972743429691164580934231578915548511341185054769998e+195998'),
> mpf('2.295150633071874195183795513608805992719016078641237e+225833'),
> mpf('4.4168863522922587926871470411448398281803390695990286e+630724'),
> mpf('5.9687942632124041381672289805552170785183139487875568e+708903'),
> mpf('3.7617642284591001005566721470201262052645423563767634e+794996')]

Comment: This works, but I can't operate further with it.

Comment: you need to use mpmath to do any further operations on them because they are no-longer python or numpy floats they are now mpmath floats, so you need to keep using their api if you don't want to lose accuracy, or just cast them to a numpy array and lose all numbers that cannot be represented by double precision.

Comment: I tried using mpmath, it comes up with an error.

Comment: keep in mind that the result is a list, not a numpy array, so you need to loop over it if you want to do any more operations like addition, etc..